# eigenenergies when Hamiltonian is $\hat{H}^2$ − $\hat{H}$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics, eigenfunctions

If the eigenenergies of the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ are $E_n$ and the eigenfunctions are $\psi_n(r)$ , what are the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the operator $\hat{H}^2$  − $\hat{H}$  ?

**Attempted solution**

$$\hat{H}^2 − \hat{H} \psi_n(r) =  \hat{H}^2 \psi_n(r) -  \hat{H} \psi_n(r) $$

$$\hat{H}^2 \psi_n(r) = \hat{H}[\hat{H}\psi_n(r)]$$

$$\hat{H}[\hat{H}\psi_n(r)] = E_n \hat{H}\psi_n(r)$$

$$\hat{H}^2  − \hat{H}\psi_n(r) = E_n^2\psi_n(r) - E_n\psi_n(r)$$

So Eigenenergies: ($E_n^2 - E_n$)

Eigenfunctions: $\psi_n(r)$

Tell me if I'm completely off track here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. The Hamiltonian is (at least, should be) self-adjoint since it is an observable. The spectral theorem says that the eigenfunctions $\psi_n$ form an orthonormal basis, and so $H^2$ can have no more eigenfunctions that are linearly independent of those of $H$. $H\psi_n=E_n\psi_n$, and we have $f(H) \psi_n = f(E_n) \psi_n$, certainly for any polynomial $f$, by iterating
$$H^k\psi_n = H^{k-1}(E_n\psi_n) = E_n (H^{k-1}\psi_n) = \dotsb = E_n^k \psi_n. $$

Comment: Thank you. This is what I suspected, but it seemed too straightforward.

Comment: @user276943:  every once in awhile even the straightforward works! ;-)

Comment: Normal operators tend to behave much better than the general case. (These include self-adjoint, unitary, anti-Hermitian, which is most of what you tend to need.)